# apache forward proxy handles https which port is not 443

Tags: apache, https, proxy

I am dealing with apache forward-proxy, i wanna it handle https that not on port 443, such as https://example.com:14430. But it didn't work. How should i configure the config file?

Here is what the http.conf like now:

```
<VirtualHost *:8002>
  ProxyRequests On
#  ProxyVia On
# <Proxy *>
#   Order allow,deny
#   Allow from all
# </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I mean i want browse https://(the https will disapper without the bracket)example.com:14430 through the apache froward-proxy, but it didn't work.

Comment: are you trying to inspect the decoded traffic?  If so, the proxy needs to sniff for a TLS handshake in the initial data sent by the client.  I don't know if Apache does this, but our product [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) can do it, which allows you to https inspect on non-standard ports.

Comment: I have solved it. Just add a config line like 'AllowCONNECT  443 563 10080 844'. And it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for answering this question so late. Actually i have solved it. The correct configure file is like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8002>
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On
<Proxy https://open.weixin.qq.com>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy> 
    AllowCONNECT  443 563 10080 8443
</VirtualHost>
```